# C++ priority queue with two comparators

Tags: c++, queue, comparator

is it possible in C++ to implement priority queue with two comparators?

Here is example:

```
struct Task
{
  int r,p,q;
  int task_number;
};


struct Greater_r
{
  bool operator()(const Task& task_a, const Task& task_b) const
  {
      return task_a.r >= task_b.r;
  }
};
```

I'd like to sort not only by "r" but also by "task_number", because when for two tasks r has same value, priority queue will sort it randomly.

Comment: `return task_a.r > task_b.r || (task_a.r == task_b.r && task_a.task_number > task_b.task_number);`

Comment: Note that the above is still one comparator. A more complicated comparator, but still one comparator. There is no need for more than one comparator.

Comment: `return std::tie(task_a.r, task_a.task_number) > std::tie(task_b.r , task_b.task_number);` (of course, it is still just on comparison operator).